# Json response with like array in array

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script

I am sure for most of you is that maybe basic. But I did not found anything in Internet, and do not understand how to handle it.

I have no problem's to deal with JSON if I have something like

```
{"ReplyData": 
 [ 
  { 
   "Lane": [], 
   "Id": 10000,
   "Title": "atitle", 
...
```

I am just asking in my code like: `parse.ReplyData[0].Lane[0]`
or `parse.ReplyData[0].Id` etc. and **that works with out problems**.

But now I have the follow situation *(it is like an array in array)*:

```
{"ReplyData": 
 [
  [
   {
    "Lane": [] 
...
```

it works with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and I receive my results there! 
But I am not sure how to handle it within my googlescript with *parse.ReplyData[]*.

1. If I try: `params.ReplyData[0].Lane` I get `"undefined"`.
2. If I try `params.ReplyData[0][0].Lane` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property "Lane" from undefined.`
3. tried even `params.ReplyData[0,0].Lane`

Any Ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: if you send your input to Stackdriver, you can easily probe the structure: `console.log(myVar);`. There you can see exact layout of the `myVar` object, e.g. named fields will be named, arrays and objects will be "openable", indices are labeled, etc

Comment: I use google script UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options) and then JSON.parse. I use Logger.log() that shows me exact layout, nevertheless it is like I have described it in my question

Comment: Replace `Logger.log()` with `console.log()` and then use `View -> Stackdriver Logging`. You will be able to do much more with the logged object. At minimum, you should paste an example result from Logger.log() here if you have it. Feel free to replace private data with example content.